Solving underdetermined nonlinear equations
Let $u,v,b \in \mathbb{R}^3$
$k_d$ is a scalar constant.
Let $u^2$ denote element wise square of $u$
$H$ is a $3\times 3$ non-invertible matrix. $G$ is a $3 \times 3$ invertible matrix.
I have an equation of form:
$Hu^2+Gv+k_dGu=b$
How to solve for $u$ and $v$.
If the term $Hu^2$ was not there it would be linear underdetermined system which i could solve by enforcing an extra constarint like minimzing norm of $v$ and $u$. But This is a nonlinear equation and I am confused.
Thanks!
